# Tomcat: Why refer incoming header it's empty in access log?

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have some redirect issues in my site.

Analizing Tomcat access log I've saw some logs like:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [18/Jun/2020:10:45:56 +0200] GET /es-es/ HTTP/1.1 302 - -
```

The log have this format: "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{SESSION}c %a %t %r %s %b %{Referer}i"

I thought that all redirects, come from an URL and its redirected to another URL, so the %{Referer}i should knowledge always.

I would like to understand, How it is possible that %{Referer}i it's empty with a redirect?

I'll appreciate all your help.

Kind regards

Comment: Because the header was absent? because there was no referer?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but the log entry shows the original request, that was redirected and not the request that came in after the redirect(?). So a referer is not always there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

@OliverGebert, what case it could not be the referer?

I understand that a redirect happened when you want to get a URL, but the server changes the request to force to get another URL.
So I can't understand, In which case the referee could be missing?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, my questions it's about, Why was no referee?